# MERGE EXCEL - How can I get all the data from table_1 no matter if the ID is in table_2?

Tags: excel, join, merge, powerquery

I am using POWER QUERY to join two tables, but the problem is that there are 28 records from table 1, but it only brings me the records that match (If it is not in table 2 the ID should still bring the row).

[image]

And it doesn't bring all the records:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing an inner join that only shows the records that match between both sets

Choose Table1 on top dropdown

Choose Table2 on bottom dropdown

Use left outer join as **Join Kind**

That will preserve all records from Table1 and add columns from Table 2 when they match

[image]